# Redirect mobile user to different .html file only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this website I am building and since I don't have any mobile layouts set up for people accessing it through phones and other small devices, I would like to kindly redirect them to a separate `mobile_redirect.html` file that contains a link and a disclaimer to the main site. From there they can still click the link and go to the main site on their phone.

Everything I have is working except for the fact that it wont let me access the main site on my phone. I believe its because my global variable `**hasBeenRedirected**` is not setting to true for a reason that I cannot figure out.

The methodology I used involves multiple `.js` files editing a single global variable `**hasBeenRedirected**` which is declared inside `index_main.js`

I attempted to make it where all the user had to do was visit the separate `mobile_redirect.html` file (of which they are automatically linked to) to set the global variable `hasBeenRedirected` to true--making it to where they could then visit the main site without being redirected, but I am clearly missing something :P

### Snippet from `index_main.js`:

```
 window.hasBeenRedirected = false; // has the user been redirected to our mobile site or not

//"things" to do as soon as our webpage loads
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";

    //if they have a tiny screen then redirect them to the mobile_redirect.html file
    if(screen.width <= 800 && !window.hasBeenRedirected){
        window.location = "http://www.summitsets.com/mobile_redirect.html";
    }
//....code continues but not relevant here
```

### mobile_redirect.js

```
//if the user has been redirected once then we wanna make sure we don't do it again!
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";

    window.hasBeenRedirected = true;
});
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The Summit Sets</title>

        <!-- Load the default CSS style sheet for our webpages */ -->
        <link href="/css/defaultStyleSheet.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />

        <!-- Load jQuery UI Library CSS Style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

        <!-- Get jQuery from internet-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Load jQuery UI Library from directory -->
        <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Load Transit CSS -> jQuery transform library -->
        <script src="/scripts/.transit script/jquery.transit.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Load our own jQuery scripts we need from directory-->
        <script src="/scripts/index_main.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "page" id = "page_1">
             <div id = "socialIconsMenu" style = "position: absolute;">
                 <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNeU3LrGEr_-peHpApCSBdQ"><img class = "socialIconsMenu_Elements" alt = "" id = "youtube" src = "/images/youtube_icon_dark.png"/></a>
                 <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/summitsets/"><img class = "socialIconsMenu_Elements" alt = "" id = "facebook" src = "/images/facebook_logo.png"/></a>
                 <a href = "https://www.instagram.com/summitsets"><img class = "socialIconsMenu_Elements" alt = "" id = "instagram" src = "/images/instagram_logo.png"/></a>
                 <!-- <div id = "otherSocialContactButton" style = "opacity: 0.0">OTHER</div> -->
             </div>

             <h1 id = "SSLogoTitle" style = "opacity:1; font-size: 81px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">The Summit Sets</h1>
             <p id = "SSLogoUnderscore" style = "opacity:1; font-size: 28px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">Integrated Entertainment</p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### mobile_redirect.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Whoops!</title>

        <!-- Get jQuery from internet-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Load the jQuery for this page -->
        <script src = "/scripts/mobile_redirect.js/" type = "text/javascript"></script>

        <link href = "/css/defaultStyleSheet.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <p style ="text-align: center; font-size: 60px; font-weight: 700;" >Looks like you accessed our site from a mobile device! </p>
        <p style ="text-align: center; font-size: 35px; font-weight: 200;" >Unfortunately our site is not yet designed to run smoothly
                                                                            on mobile devices. You may continue if you'd like by
                                                                            using the link below, but many or all features may either
                                                                            not function properly--or not functional at all.
                                                                            For an optimal experience, we highly suggest using
                                                                            a laptop, desktop, or high performance tablet.
                                                                            We apologize for the inconvenience.</p>
        <a href = "http://www.summitsets.com/"><p style = "font-weight: 500; font-size: 45px; text-align: center;">Take me to the main site</p></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems like a big post but I feel as if the solution is quite simple. I just wanted to provide as many resources to my problem as possible.

You can actually test this live if you'd like by going to my website on your phone. You'll notice how you cant access the main site cause it keeps redirecting you.

http://www.summitsets.com

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Are you Ajaxing the page loads? (Answer is NO!) If not there is no such thing as a global variable that lasts across page loads. Drop a cookie value instead.

Comment: Set a browser cookie or store the session state on the server.

Comment: You cannot have cross-page variables unless you are using Ajax to load the pages into a 'single' page, or you have some server side script handling that. You should look at either cookies or local storage which is used to save certain client side variables for a specific client

Comment: I am fairly new to building websites so I have never even heard of using Ajax to load pages. I will have to do some homework on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest the use of cookies , because on redirections javascript  lost all data saved in memory .

So in your mobile _redirect.js instead of global object better set a cookie :

document.cookie = "isMobile=true";

And then you can access  cookies even if page is redirected like

var foo = document.cookie;

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Do you have any links to popular tutorials on using cookies to store variables such as these?

Comment: Alex updated my answer , I couldn't write more detailed because I'm in mobile!